# C++ CLI / TS3 Client crashes on plugin

Tags: debugging, plugins, crash, c++-cli, teamspeak

Sooo...
I have written a plugin, and the whole plugin works fine.
ONLY PROBLEM:
My TS3 Client crashes.

To give a context:

(Warning: That code is just poorly pasted. On GitHub, it crashes at line 270 and 285)

```
// Helper Function

    String^ getChannelName(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID) {
        char* tmp;
        if (ts3Functions.getChannelVariableAsString(serverConnectionHandlerID, channelID, CHANNEL_NAME, &tmp) == ERROR_ok) {
            return marshal_as<String^>(tmp);
        }
        else
        {
            return "ERROR_GETTING_CHANNELNAME";
        }
    }
    void assemble_a() {
        List<String^>^ clients;
        List<String^>^ channel;

        // Some middlepart here, but I made sure it works as it should

        // And the actual part where it is crashing
        if (resChL == ERROR_ok) {
            for (int i = 0; channelListPtr[i]; ++i) {
                String^ a = getChannelName(schid, channelListPtr[i]);
                const char* b = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(a)).ToPointer();
                ts3Functions.logMessage(b, LogLevel_DEBUG, "DEBUG_VC", schid);
                if (String::IsNullOrEmpty(a) == false) {
                    channel->Add(a); // It crashes RIGHT at this point
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So I am asking on the TS3 forum for a long time, got a lot of answers, and noone could tell me why it actually crashes, and I didn't manage to figure it out on my own either.

It does actually print the channel name `[*spacer0]t` but as soon as it should append it to the String List, it crashes.
It throws the message `The thread has tried to write or read from a virtual address that it does not have the accesspermissions for.`

I seriously have no idea what to do, trying to fix it now for over 2 weeks.

For full context: [GitHub Sourcecode](https://github.com/WhOoKie/TS3WKVC/blob/master/plugin.cpp#L270)

Sorry if this question MIGHT be a little out of topic here (Is it? I don't know...) but I don't really know what to do with that problem anymore...

EDIT:
Errormessage from try/catch is:
`System.NullReferebceException: The Objectreference was not set to the Objectinstance, occured in tsapi.assembleGrammar()`

Comment: System.NullReferebceException: The Objectreference was not set to the Objectinstance, occured in tsapi.assembleGrammar()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String^>^ channel;
...
channel->Add(a);
```

`channel` is null. You need to initialize it with something, probably `gcnew List<String^>()`. I'm not sure why you're getting an access denied message instead of NullReferenceException.

### Other issues

- Make sure you're handling all the unmanaged strings properly. For example, does `getChannelVariableAsString` require a call to explicitly free the buffer? Be absolutely sure to call `FreeHGlobal` to free the memory that `StringToHGlobalAnsi` allocated for you.

Comment: The strings are fine, I made that sure. I am using marshal_as<>() and StringToHGlobalAnsi()

Comment: The strings are not fine, you're only calling `FreeHGlobal` in one of the three spots where you're calling `StringToHGlobalAnsi`. This is a memory leak.

Comment: Really?? Well, I was working on changing the StringToHGlobal to marshal_as<>()

Comment: Using marshal_as to convert to either std::string or char* with a marshal_context would also solve the memory leak.

Comment: The thing is, I cannot find more than one case where I used StringToHGlobalAnsi(), and I did free it there. So I guess it is fine then?

Comment: 1) In this question. 2) https://github.com/WhOoKie/TS3WKVC/blob/master/plugin.cpp#L267 3) https://github.com/WhOoKie/TS3WKVC/blob/master/plugin.cpp#L282

Comment: Alright, I removed those anyways now, those were just used for debugging.